# Subscribe to Websocket API using Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, websocket

I'd like to create a simple Laravel command that regularly checks **wss://www.bitmex.com/realtime** websocket api, I'm not sure where to start with that. Any ideas would help

Comment: Don't you want to do this from the client? (js)

Comment: No, from php on a Laravel command (with runs every 5 minutes)

Comment: It can be done, but it sounds like a design flaw. Websockets are there to keep a connection open. If you open and close a socket every 5 minutes you lose all value of using sockets.

Comment: Oh I understand. Thanks! Any idea how I can do this with JS thru my Laravel project? or should it be a standalone JS app?

Comment: You don't really need Laravel (or any server side code) to diplay the realtime data from a websocket. But you probably have other features to implement.

Comment: Ok, wanted to use my Laravel app so I could post results from the webscocket api to my DB for later references.

Comment: You want to cache the result. In that case, you are right. What you need is a `Websocket Client` for PHP. For example this one: https://github.com/ratchetphp/Pawl. Just remember that websockets are more of a stream, you should not ask for data every 5 minutes. You should just keep the connection open